# Unable to open Safari app on iPhone simulator while running Selenium test using ios-driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, mobile

I am trying to automate mobile web testing using [ios-driver](https://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/). The safari browser does not open even though the simulator launches.

The configuration as shown on terminal by running the command `java -jar ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar -newSessionTimeoutSec 40 -port 5555` is:

```
Running on: Mac OS X 10.10 (x86_64)
Using java: 1.8.0_45
Using Xcode install: /Applications/Xcode.app
Using instruments: version:6.3.2, build: 57082
Using iOS version 8.3
iOS >= 6.0. Safari and hybrid apps are supported.
Applications :
CFBundleName=Safari,CFBundleVersion=600.1.4,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app
```

The Java code I used is as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = IOSCapabilities.iphone("Safari");
caps.setCapability(IOSCapabilities.SIMULATOR, true);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"), caps);
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

The following lines are displayed on terminal:

```
59:05:611 WARNING InstrumentsCommandLine.start instruments crashed (40 SEC)
59:06:040 WARNING NewSessionNHandler.safeStart Instruments failed to start in the allocated time ( 40sec):Didn't get the capability back.Most likely, instruments crashed at startup.
59:06:476 WARNING NewSessionNHandler.safeStart app has crashed at startup :normal
59:06:482 INFO IOSServerManager.findAllMatchingApplications Safari application requested for SDK version: 8.3
```

Any help from anyone would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up when UI automation option is not selected for your device.
Follow the below mentioned steps to enable it:
1.Navigate to your device settings.
2.Open Developers option.
3.Enable the UI automation option.

Now try running your cases.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing to try is to increase `newSessionTimeoutSec` to `80` or `120` secs.

   > I.e. run instead:
   >   `java -jar ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar -newSessionTimeoutSec 120 -port 5555`

---

2. If it doesn't helps below is mdiwakar's solution from a [discussion of similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/issues/221):

   > I am using mac VM, it seems the issue was instruments were crashing
   >   and i believe VM were very slow. I did the following
   >
   > 1) Added Safari Option to have clean session capability
   >   
   > 2) Upgraded to use selenium 2.37 instead of 2.35
   >   
   > 3) Increased the TIMEOUT_SEC to 40 from 20 NewSessionHandler.java(configurable param)
   >   
   > 4) Small change args.add9("-v") to InstrumentsApple.java
   >
   > With the above mentioned changes I am able to run my tests with less
   >   frequent crashes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the first approach but was getting the same error. Also, I have seen the mentioned github issue link. But it was not helpful in my case. But when I installed Xcode 6.2 with sdk 8.2 it ran successfully on iPhone 5s simulator. Don't know what the error was while working with the newer version (8.3) of Xcode.